# Reading a unstructured csv into Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a unstructured csv file that I would like to read into the Pandas data frame.

Here is the sample csv:

`customer_id,123,acct1,1000,10,acct2,2000,20,acct3,3000,30
customer_id,456,acct1,4000,40,acct2,5000,50
customer_id,789,acct3,6000,60
customer_id,888,acct1,7000,,acct2,,70
customer_id,999`

Each line represents a customer, accounts associated with the customer and variables related to customer's accounts. Customers do not have the same accounts, so we are not guaranteed to get a row with same accounts.

If account exists, there will be a predetermined number of variables following account's name (2 for each account in this case). However, even if account is present some of the variables related to the account might be missing (for ex., where customer_id is 888).

If a customer doesn't have an account, it will not be present in the record for the customer.

Here is what the desired dataframe looks like:

`customer_id | acct1_bal | acct_1_del | acct2_bal | acct_2_del | acct3_bal | acct_3_del |
123         | 1000      | 10         | 2000      | 20         | 3000      | 30         |
456         | 4000      | 40         | 5000       | 50        | NaN       | NaN        |
789         | NaN       | NaN        | NaN       | NaN        | 6000      | 60         |
888         | 7000      | NaN        | NaN       | 70         | NaN       | NaN        |
999         | NaN       | NaN        | NaN       | NaN        | NaN       | NaN        |`

The above dataframe will have seven columns. It will be populated with NaNs where account doesn't exist or account's variable is missing.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

[image]You will get the desired result by this way, use pandas:
You can optimise the code as per your use,

```
import csv, json
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {}
with open('input_dataframe.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    raw_data['customer_id'] = []
    raw_data['acct1_bal'] = []    
    raw_data['acct_1_del'] = []
    raw_data['acct2_bal'] = []
    raw_data['acct_2_del'] = []
    raw_data['acct3_bal'] = []
    raw_data['acct_3_del'] = []
    for row in spamreader:
        raw_data['customer_id'].append((row[0]).split(',')[1])
        raw_data['acct1_bal'].append((row[0]).split(',')[3])
        raw_data['acct_1_del'].append((row[0]).split(',')[4])
        raw_data['acct2_bal'].append((row[0]).split(',')[6])
        raw_data['acct_2_del'].append((row[0]).split(',')[7])
        raw_data['acct3_bal'].append((row[0]).split(',')[9])
        raw_data['acct_3_del'].append((row[0]).split(',')[10])

df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['customer_id', 'acct1_bal', 'acct_1_del', 'acct2_bal', 'acct_2_del', 'acct3_bal', 'acct_3_del']).replace('','NaNs')
df.to_csv('output_dataframe.csv')
```

Comment: What is the output data frame you are getting? This is throwing an IndexError because rows don't have guaranteed number of items.

Comment: i have uploaded the screenshot of the result, you only have to change a bit to get desired output, if you share your input csv file then it would be helpful form me to suggest you .  the result will vary as per the structure on input csv file

Comment: I am not sure how you got the result. I am getting IndexError when reading second row because acct3_bal does not exist in that row.

Comment: Thanks! csv sample in my question is a good representation of the data.

Comment: By the way, I see what you are doing, however I would be more interested in learning whether we can do anything to read this csv using pandas functionality or some other library.

Comment: pandas will read your csv,
http://www.gregreda.com/2013/10/26/intro-to-pandas-data-structures/